Is it advisable to use port expanders in a self developed testing device?
In the company where I work, we developed our own testing device to test boards after their assembly. We conduct functional testing and look for short circuits and other manufacturing and assembly errors. For some time, the number of ports going to the DUT from the testing device was enough (let's say 60 of them) since the projects were small. But then came the moment when these conditional 60 outputs are no longer enough to cover all the outputs of the new DUT. And I don't really know what to do in this situation. The simplest solution that comes to my mind is to install several port expanders that will communicate with the testing device via I2C. But here is the problem, won't this be overengineering? An outside opinion is needed. Maybe there are some other approaches to solving such problems?

Why do you consider port expanders overengineering? You might be able to multiplex signals or something but port expanders are a relatively simple way to monitor multiple inputs and many of them have features that can add real functionality to your system.

I can't be completely sure that this is not over engineering. Because I just don't know how it can be done better. That's why I'm asking if it doesn't seem excessive at first glance. It didn't seem that way to you, thank you for writing about it.

Side note: SPI port expanders are also available and can be much easier to use and at much higher frequencies than I2C.   I've used MCP23S17 for similar purposes and it performs very well.  We'd need to know more about your test rig to evaluate what level of effort would be justified.

Is it possible, that the DUT can test itself if external I/O loopback is connected?

Thank you for your answers. I will answer new comments in order:

In this particular task, I do not need high frequencies, and I2C will suffice. Another good thing about it is that it only takes up two wires. For the SPI chip, you will have to allocate 3 wires plus one wire for each new chip for CS, which I cannot afford, while I2C only needs an address.


But still, thank you for your answer, I will keep this in mind for the future. The test bench in this task is engaged in finding short circuits and functional testing if necessary, for example, if this is some special microcontroller unit on the board being tested. The board is tested through pogopins soldered into the testing matrix, on which I plan to place the circuitry I need. And then this matrix is ​​connected to the main testing board on which the main microcontroller is located. Accordingly, each new board needs its own matrix.


If I understood the question correctly, then yes, it is possible. And it seems that this is how it is arranged in the code. But the problem is that at the moment I simply don’t have enough I/O for testing, hence the question of whether the solution with port expanders is appropriate.


My three new comments are in fact one answer.
